# Where is the path to the downloaded jars file when Grails is resolving dependencies

Tags: grails

Grails resolves dependencies and downloads some jars. But I can't find where the downloaded file path. [image]

And the command `locate` also can't find these jars.

My Operator System is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I can `locate` those files in `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1` on OS X and CentOS just fine!?

Answer (score 1):

It should be under `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1`